# React - Empty Array When Rendering JSON Data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch

Why is an empty array created when rendering this JSON array? [**See attached screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAdu9.png)  I assume the constructor is just initiating it with a null value and filling it at a later point.

New to Javascript + React and just want to make sure I am understanding what is happening.  I will also accept critique on the garbage code that is below. [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/amishpanda/pen/BZwwGa)

```
class Jobs extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const jobs = this.props.jobs;
    console.log(jobs);
    const formattedJobs = jobs.map((job) =>
      <ul key={job.id}> 
        <div class="company">{job.company_name}</div>
        <div class="title">{job.title}</div>
      </ul>
    );
    return(
      <div>{formattedJobs}</div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state={
      jobs:[]
    }
  var myUrl = "https://codepen.io/jobs.json";
  fetch(myUrl)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => this.setState({jobs: json.jobs}));
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="header">
        <h1 id="header-title">Job Postings</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="content">
        <Jobs jobs={this.state.jobs}/>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the jobs from an ajax request wich is async. Thats why the initial value is an empty array.

App.render is executed before your ajax request is finished and thats why you are not givin any job to the Jobs component. Once the ajax is finished, the jobs array is filled with the results and sendeded to the Jobs component to render the results of that ajax request.

Comment: Got it, thank you.  That makes sense.  I had more reading to do about ajax, fetch, and Javascript but I'm seeing it now.

Answer (score 1):

always use fetch statements in ComponentDidMount as it is called just after your component is rendered for the very first time

```
ComponentDidMount {
 fetch(myUrl)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => this.setState({jobs: json.jobs}));
}
```

Comment: Will do, I was avoiding handling it correctly just so I could get the thing to print out.  But I'll update this to handle all the cases.

Answer (score 1):

## Jobs component

- always be nice for default props - component can / will render before fetch returns response
- replace `class` with `className` as first one is restricted word in `JSX`
- `ul` can only contains `li` childs - not `div`
- nice for use `key` property when you iterate over collection

## App component

- there is place for suppor unexpected response, you can set new state like `error` and support it
- please consider with component is responsible to support errors and spinners- `App` or `Jobs`

## Ract application

```
class Jobs extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { jobs } = this.props;
    const formattedJobs = jobs.map(job =>
      <ul key={job.id}>
        <li className="company">{job.company_name}</li>
        <li className="title">{job.title}</li>
      </ul>
    );

    return <div>{formattedJobs}</div>;
  }
}

Jobs.defaultProps = {
  jobs: []
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      jobs: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://codepen.io/jobs.json")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        if (!Array.isArray(response.jobs)) {
          throw new Error(
            `Expected response but got ${JSON.stringify(response.jobs)}`
          );
        } else {
          return response.jobs;
        }
      })
      .then(jobs => this.setState({ jobs }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <div className="header">
          <h1 id="header-title">Job Postings</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="content">
          <Jobs jobs={this.state.jobs} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  Updating to meet those concerns you raised.  I'm getting the hang of it now.